# $orderBy with duplicate property in odata v4

Tags: c#, asp.net, duplicates, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following models:

```
public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public int FieldGroupId { get; set; }
}

public class FieldGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Field> Field { get; set; }
}
```

And what I am want to do is a query where I can order first by the group and then by the field, like:

```
http://localhost:44300/API/odata/IntFieldSet?$count=true&$expand=FieldGroup&$orderby=FieldGroup/Order,Order
```

However, when I try it I receive the following error:

```
Duplicate property named 'Order' is not supported in '$orderby'.
```

Although they have the same name, they are not the same field. If I try order by fields with different names or only one of those per time, it works. Ex:

```
$orderby=FieldGroup/Order,Name   ||   $orderby=FieldGroup/Order   ||   $orderby=Order
```

It used to work on odata v3 but not anymore that I am using odata v4.

Anyone have faced this problem before. Can you help me to find out a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue using WebAPI OData 5.6 and 5.7.
However they say they fixed it in version WebAPI Odata 5.7: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/376
Will wait for publication of the update.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed now.
The correct query should look something like:

```
http://localhost:44300/API/odata/IntFieldSet?$count=true&$expand=FieldGroup&$orderby=FieldGroup/Order asc,Order desc
```

It will rougly be translate to:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.FieldGroup.Order).ThenByDescending(x => x.Order);
```

Here's an example from odata.org:

http://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/Airports?$orderby=Name%20asc,%20Location/Address%20desc